# Migrating from Codepen/Jfiddle. Begining to take your code to web. What is correct protocol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, hosting

I have been learning to code using tools such as codepen and Jfiddle.

These tools are brilliant and they hold your hand in linking your documents and libraries such as JQuery, But because of this I have found a barrier in what to do next.

What is the correct protocol for taking your code and using it on the web. linking documents and containing libraries?

Sorry if this a basic/stupid question, I don't intend it to appear too subjective.

Basically:

I have code on codepen and Jfiddle. How to I take it to use independently of these systems?
What is the correct Process?
What is the right code snippets to use?
How should I correctly arange my sepparate HTML/CSS/JS documents?
How should I arrange any extras (such as JQuery)?

Any help and/or links will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen Lets you export your work directly. It will package up your HTML, CSS and JS and any external libraries Such as jQuery (If you have them selected) into a clearly named folder for you to use offline.

Alternately you can Do this yourself very easily. Create your respective files copy and paste the code and give them clear names. Then link to them in the head of your HTML like so:

```
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<link REL="StyleSheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="css/sheet.css">
<script src="js/JSBrains.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can link to files hosed online like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

MrB